# onmousemouve work but hover effetc and click doesn't work in reatcjs app

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i working on my project and  i would like to do the mouse effect like on this wordpress template, http://preview.themeforest.net/item/consultio-consulting-business-wordpress/full_screen_preview/25376496?_ga=2.61545708.1311804999.1617452015-579954703.1617357573

But in my projetc i have that :

```js
let circle = document.getElementById("ct-mouse-move"); 

const onMouseMove = (e) =>{
    circle.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
    circle.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
};
document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)
```

```css
#ct-mouse-move {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
}



#ct-mouse-move .circle-cursor--outer {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(14, 128, 246, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -ms-border-radius: 30px;
    -o-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-top: -17px;
    margin-left: -16px;
    -webkit-transition: all 50ms linear 0ms;
    -khtml-transition: all 50ms linear 0ms;
    -moz-transition: all 50ms linear 0ms;
    -ms-transition: all 50ms linear 0ms;
    -o-transition: all 50ms linear 0ms;
    transition: all 50ms linear 0ms;
}

#ct-mouse-move .circle-cursor--inner {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #0e80f6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -ms-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ct-mouse-move" style="top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    <div class="circle-cursor circle-cursor--outer"></div>
    <div class="circle-cursor circle-cursor--inner"></div>
</div>
```

so the onmousemouve work but de hover effect and click action doesn't work 
how can i solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay can you explain me a bit more cause I don't see react anywhere here and if you're doing this in react it's way too wrong and you should consider reading documentation.

Comment: the part of the html code, I put it in the index.html page, as well as the script part. and the css is in my App.css page

Comment: for example, on my home page, i import the navbar, there are my links but when i hover or click on a link, it doesn't work!